# "let" internal shell command doesn't work in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I did

```
a=1234 
let "a=a+1"
```

on command line and it's fine. But when I do the same in a shell script. It prints out an error that "let: not found".
Here is the script file.

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1234;
let "a=a+1";
echo "$a";
```

Thanks,

Comment: You're probably using a different shell - do you have a shebang line at the start of your script ?

Comment: Maybe use `a=1234` ? Check this: `help|grep let` too.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` - What it says?

Comment: That first line is invalid. Are you sure you're writing a shell script?

Comment: yes i put a shebang. #!/bin/sh

Comment: If you're really using unix and not linux, then using `#~/bin/sh` is getting you the bourne shell. From your command line (when it works with `let`), type `echo $SHELL` and use that for your `#!/bin/...`. Good luck.

Comment: Can you believe this guy???? https://github.com/drbeco/killgracefully/issues/1

Comment: I'm not responsible for that github issue ;-). It's not me. @DrBeco LOL

Comment: Hi @John, I'm glad it was not you, thank you for clarifying that. ;) Still the question holds: can you believe that guy!? LOL Have a nice day. (I've updated the subject in the issue to not imply it was you or give that impression)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is likely that `/bin/sh` is not the same as, or does not behave the same as, your normal shell.  For example, when `bash` is invoked as `/bin/sh`, it provides a subset of its normal features.

So, you may need to change your shebang line to use a different shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

You don't need the semi-colons at the ends of the lines.

Answer (score 19):

Do not use `let`. Use [POSIX arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04): `a=$(($a+1))`. This is guaranteed to work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

See at: http://www.hlevkin.com/Shell_progr/hellobash.htm

The correct is:

```
a=1234;
b=1;
a=`expr $a + $b`;
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  this worked for me even on bare `sh` in an alpine container, however - the provided link is broken

Answer (score 2):

You should use `let a=a+1` without quotes

Answer (score 1):

It's the '$a' of '$a=1234' that is killing you.

The shell does all $ substitutions and THEN evaluates the expression. As a result it saw "=1234" because there was no value to $a.

Use -x to see this.

```
  bash -x your-script
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your actual shell with the following command in the command line:


*echo $SHELL*

It will provide a shell name, use that instead of /bin/sh at the first line of your script.

Comment: yes the problem was with the shebang. I changed it to #!/bin/bash (echo $SHELL prints bash) and it works. But what is the purpose of shebang then? I thought it invokes the appropriate shell for executing the script. (I have sh in /bin). Or is it that let is not supported in bourne shell?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the shell name using

   `echo $SHELL`
2. Change the first line of the script accordingly to

   `#!/bin/bash`

   or

   `#!/bin/ksh`

   instead of `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score -2):

```sh
c=1
d=1
for i in `ls`
do
    if [ -f $i ]
    then
        echo "$c -> $i"
        c=`expr $c + 1`
    fi
done
c=`expr $c - 1`
echo no. of files $c
for i in `ls`
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        echo "$d -> $i"
        d=`expr $d + 1`
    fi
done
d=`expr $d - 1`
echo no. of direcrories $d
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.